# Load test and Scale MVC web api service

Tags: asp.net-web-api, scalability, performance-testing

I would like to load test my MVC web api and get the best hardware configurations or number of load balanced servers to achieve specific number of concurent requests.

But I do not know where to start. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sounds like a plan (rather than a question). There are load testing tools out there, so go for it.

Comment: I would like to know, form where to start

Comment: well, there's no point stress testing a website without some feedback on how it's performing so maybe begin with identifying and logging key metrics? I'm not sure this question fits SO question policy so you might get a better response by starting with something and coming back with specific questions later. Best of luck!

Comment: as a start, you can try using Apache Benchmarking tool.

Answer (score 2):

As regards to ASP.NET Web API, the steps are pretty straight forward.

- create a unit test project for your web api method(s). check [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-with-aspnet-web-api) out
- add a load test to the test project check [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pandeypradip/load-testing-of-web-api/) out
- perform the load test in the cloud. Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn250793.aspx) and [this](http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/load-test-your-app-vs).

Note that the last step requires that you have visual studio ultimate and a visual studio online account. Your visual studio online account gets you 15,000 user minutes free every month to load test your app. You should be able to glean useful information in the test results to help in your decisions e.g how many VM instances you might need, etc.